# Jquery File Upload (hayageek plugin) error case with json from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-file-upload

today I'm trying to use the jquery upload file (https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/) plugin and it's working without any problems. But obviously I have to test the error situation as well.
I read that to send an error message from backend to the plugin, I should send a json like this:

```
{"jquery-upload-file-error":"File already exists"}
```

(source: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php).

My backend is in php and I have a lot of problem to test an upload failed. I'm using this very simple code:

```
$ret = array();

$ret["jquery-upload-file-error"] = "File already exists";
echo json_encode($ret);
die();
```

and with firebug I'm able to see the backend response:

```
{"jquery-upload-file-error":"File already exists"}
```

but the upload always finishes properly..

The HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://rawgithub.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/css/uploadfile.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile(
        {
            url         : "../php/upload.php",
            fileName    : "myfile"
        }
    );

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I doing wrong? Or is a bug of the plugin?

Comment: what do you mean by: `but the upload always finishes properly` what is the criteria?

Comment: Since I'm sending a json with the error param filled, I expect that the jquery upload plugin would show an error instead of the standard result "done"..
In fact if you see the above code I'm not getting the file from frontend to backend (by means of the die function). I'm only sending an error message, but the plugin however shows the upload as it were completed

Comment: you didn't show your js and html. could you provide a link to your page? you wrote: `and with firebug I'm able to see the backend response:

{"files":[{"name":"prova.txt","size":10,"error":"Filetype not allowed"}]}` so what object do you observe there?

Comment: unfortunately I did a mistake and I was referring to the (blueimp) jQuery File Upload documentation while I was using the code of (hayageek) jQuery Upload File. Very sorry (the name was too similar!). But however the problem remains: reading in the forum of hayageek/jquery-upload-file the message to send an error to the plugin is very clear but although now I'm using the right message format, the plugin doesn't show the error...
PS: I update the post with the right situation

Comment: I was able to test the behaviour of the plugin in case of a backend error, sending to the plugin a HTTP error message, with this php code:
**header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);**
Problem resolved :)